# A few wordings from the article about Einstein

Tags: meaning

"a healthy dose of extreme misogyny" to his xenophobia with the observation - This was what I read from the article but what was the meaning of that, especially the wording "a healthy dose"? Anyone who can help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally, the [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=B3GYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22a+healthy+dose+of+extreme+misogyny%22&source=bl&ots=K2sqnxm_wN&sig=ACfU3U1qlmKxo0emWQECrHMIPAb2rGFWdw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWpfTYgKfkAhVbPn0KHSfNDZkQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20healthy%20dose%20of%20extreme%20misogyny%22&f=false) appears to have been written by a biographer who was intent on defaming Einstein.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  This type of question typically gets closed on our site.  We recommend that you do some research prior to posting and tell us how you've attempted to find the answer.

Comment: That said, *healthy dose* is being used ironically here.  Extreme misogyny is never something that someone takes for their health.  Rather, it's implying that fair bit of extreme misogyny was present in his xenophobia.

Comment: 2 times' "Great job" for Benjamin, and thanks to Jason as well.

Answer (score 3):

In that usage, "[healthy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/healthy?s=ts)" is being used informally to mean "fairly large."

See the following citation from dictionary.com:

> healthy - 5. *informal* fairly large : I bought a healthy number of books.

Comment: Great job, Benjamin.

Comment: While you're correct about the meaning of the word healthy, it's not explaining the idiom healthy dose.

Comment: @DavidM Most likely because it's not an idiom. As per the answer, it means *a [fairly large] dose*.

Comment: @JasonBassford It's being used idiomatically here.  Misogyny is not something that is usually dosed out.

Comment: Just because the language is figurative, that doesn't make it an idiom.  "Healthy dose" isn't an idiom.  Google "healthy dose," you won't find it listed anywhere as an idiom.  Google "get cold feet," and you will see that listed as an idiom everywhere.

Comment: By the way, an idiom is an expression whose meaning cannot be surmised from the words themselves.  That's why idioms are defined in dictionaries, because their definitions cannot be otherwise inferred based simply on the meanings of the words they contain.  The meaning of "a healthy dose of extreme misogyny" can be readily surmised from the words themselves and is in no dictionary anywhere.

Comment: 2 times' "Great job" for Benjamin, and thanks to Jason as well.